# uploading chunck more then 13 mb is aborting

Tags: php, ajax, chunking

In php i write code to upload the file by using chunck. it is working in local server. but in live server is not uploading more then 13 mb file is aborting. Same time server post size, execution time are incressed but still it is aborting while ajax call send.

the below page is html page

```
    <script>
function upload(fileInputId, fileIndex) {
    // take the file from the input
    //document.getElementById('art_frm').method = 'PUT';
    $.browser.safari = ($.browser.webkit && !(/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())));
    if ($.browser.safari) {
        var safari = 1;
    }else{
        var safari = -1;
    }
    var ms_ie = false;
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    var file        = document.getElementById(fileInputId).files[fileIndex]; 
    var reader      = new FileReader();
    var fileName    = file.name;
    var rand_num    = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000000000) + 1);
    var type        = getExtension(file.name);
    var id          = document.getElementById('id')!=null ? document.getElementById('id').value : '';
    var folder      = '';
    fileName        = rand_num+fileName.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s\.]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
    $("#randomName").val(fileName);
    // reading file 
    if (typeof(reader.readAsBinaryString) == 'undefined') {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); // alternatively you can use readAsDataURL
    } else {
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file); // alternatively you can use readAsDataURL
    }

    reader.onloadend  = function(evt) {
        // create XHR instance
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // send the file through POST
        if(id){
            var params  = 'action=uploadfile&file-name='+fileName+'&id='+id;
            var url     = '/upload-picture.php';
        }
        else{
            var params  = 'action=uploadfile&file-name='+fileName;
            var url     = '/upload-picture.php';
        }   
        if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
                url     = url + '?browser=IE';
            }else{
                url     = url + '?browser=NOT-IE';
        }
        setTimeout(function() {  xhr.abort(); alert("ajax call timeout!")  },40000000);

        xhr.open("POST",url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", fileName);

        // make sure we have the sendAsBinary method on all browser
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary = function(text){
            var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { 
                ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
            }

            //blob code
            try{
                var blob = new Blob( [data]);
            }
            catch(e){
                // TypeError old chrome and FF
                window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder 
                                    || window.WebKitBlobBuilder 
                                    || window.MozBlobBuilder 
                                    || window.MSBlobBuilder;
                if(e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder){
                    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                    bb.append([data.buffer]);
                    var blob = bb.getBlob();
                }
                else if(e.name == "InvalidStateError"){
                    // InvalidStateError FF13 WinXP
                    var blob = new Blob( [data.buffer]);
                }
                else{
                    // We're screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely   
                }
            }   
            //end blob
            this.send(blob);
        }

        // let's track upload progress
        var eventSource = xhr.upload || xhr;
        eventSource.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            // get percentage of how much of the current file has been sent
            var position    = e.position || e.loaded;
            var total       = e.totalSize || e.total;
            var percentage  = Math.round((position/total)*100);
            var myBar       = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
            var divBar      = document.getElementById('bar'+fileIndex);
            var str_disp    = '';
            var str_color   = '';
            if(divBar!=null) {
                if(position >= file.size) {
                    str_disp    =   'Loading..';
                    str_color   =   '#4679BD';
                } else {
                    str_disp    =   percentage+"%";
                    str_color   =   '#9DC3FF';
                }
                divBar.innerHTML    =   "<label>&nbsp;</label><font style='color:"+str_color+";background:#fff;'><div style='width:270px;float:left;text-align:center;position:relative;margin:0 0 10px;float:left;'><span style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0px;width:100%;text-align:center;'> </span><span style='background:"+str_color+";display:block;height:5px;border:1px solid #9DC3FF;width:"+percentage+"%'>&nbsp;</span>"+str_disp+"</div></font>";
            } else {
                myBar.innerHTML = myBar.innerHTML+"<div id='bar"+fileIndex+"'></div>";
            }
            //document.getElementById("profile_pic").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '';
            // here you should write your own code how you wish to proces this
        });
        // state change observer - we need to know when and if the file was successfully uploaded
        console.log(xhr); 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log(xhr.readyState,xhr.responseText); 
            if(xhr.readyState == 4)  {
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                // process success\
                if(xhr.responseText == '') {
                    alert("file is not uploaded");
                    return false;
                } else {

                    document.getElementById("progress-bar").innerHTML='uploaded!';
                }                               
            } else {
                }
            }
        };

        // start sending
        xhr.mySendAsBinary(evt.target.result);
    };
}
function getFiles(){
    var imageFiles  = document.getElementById("profile_pic");
    var i = 0
    var myBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
    myBar.innerHTML = myBar.innerHTML+"<label>&nbsp;</label><div id='bar"+i+"' style='float:left;'><font style='color:#9DC3FF'>"+imageFiles.files[i].name+" uploading..<br/></font><div style='width:270px;border:1px solid #9DC3FF;text-align:center;position:relative;margin:0 0 10px;'><span style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0px;width:100%;text-align:center;'> </span><span style='background:#9DC3FF;display:block;height:5px;width:2%'>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
    upload('profile_pic',i);
}
</script>
<body>
```

```
</body>
```

the blow page is php page upload-picture.php

```
  <?php
define("ARTS_PIC_TEMP_THUMBNAIL_PATH","uploads/");
$uploaded_file_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
$opt                = uploadingArts($uploaded_file_name);
function uploadingArts($filename=''){
        //$filename=($filename);
        $path_of = ARTS_PIC_TEMP_THUMBNAIL_PATH.$filename;
        $dest_dir = ARTS_PIC_TEMP_THUMBNAIL_PATH;
        $brwName = getBrowser();
        if($brwName=='Internet Explorer'){
            //for IE
            $content = file_get_contents('php://input'); //the string we get contains 2 parts
            $content = str_replace(' ','+',$content); // we need to replace spaces by plusses
            $content = split(",",$content); // we do not need the first part of the string (the one with the file type).
            $content = base64_decode($content[1]); 
            file_put_contents($dest_dir.''.$filename, $content);
            return true; 
        }   
        else { //other than IE
            // read contents from the input stream
            $inputHandler = fopen('php://input', "r");
            $fileHandler = fopen($path_of, "w+");
            // save data from the input stream
            while(true) {
                //4096
                $buffer = fgets($inputHandler, 1096);
                if (strlen($buffer) == 0) {
                    fclose($inputHandler);
                    fclose($fileHandler);
                    return true;
                }
                fwrite($fileHandler, $buffer);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

after going ajax call to upload-picture.php file call get aborted after some time in only live server.
what i have to do for upload laoding large files like 38,39 mb files ?